# Starter proublem after replacing...BMW starts but now has weird grinding sound

Tags: noise, starter

Changed starter in **2007 BMW 335i** now makes weird sound after start, can this be the a faulty starter? Had starter in for 9 days before it started making sound. Any siggestions?

Comment: has it got dirty? clutch dust etc? Did you leave a fixing bolt loose and it is now not engaging properly?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the noise just while cranking the engine, or does it occur all the time (during cranking as well as engine running)?

Comment: Give more information about the noise. Does the noise appear only when the motor starts running, or does it persist? What does it sound like: high-pitch, low-pitch, repetitive knocking, clicking, screech?